# VPN crashed, need to reset my DNS to normal defaults to restore internet

Tags: networking, vpn, dns

I have a weird issue that normally I'd fix by just rebooting my machine, but since I'm out of the country I don't have access to the system and can't type the boot password. So rebooting isn't an option.

(I am on Lubuntu 16.04LTS, by the way)

But when I left my country I was running a VPN client and would ssh tunnel in, open a VNC window, and access my home machine. The VPN part actually doesn't matter at all now, I had simply left it running when I left.

But it crashed and immediately I lost all web browsing and email capability. I can still SSH to the machine and type command lines, but I can't use "apt-get" to install anything.

So what I need to do (I think) is somehow reset or restart the DNS servers. I don't know if this is called flushing the DNS cache, but if so, it seems like I need to download a non-included tool to do that. Which sucks because apt-get no longer works.

Can anyone suggest a fix for this? I tried restarting the VPN too but it didn't work. The VPN client failed to start...and I still had the same connection issues.

All I want is to be able to access the internet again like normal. Seems like it wouldn't be too tricky....just need to know how to reset/restart things...again, without rebooting!

Thank you!

Comment: What is in `/etc/network/interfaces` ?

Comment: "auto lo
iface lo inet loopback"

Just those two lines (and sorry, the comment doesn't include the line break..."auto lo" is the first line.

Comment: Your network is likely being managed by `networkmanager` then.  I always use manual config via the interfaces file - check the manual for it - https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html you want to check your DNS servers (make sure they aren't pointing at VPN IPs) and if needed, reset them.

Comment: Thank you, I checked this but I don't need to configure anything different (at least I don't think so), just need to "simulate" the process that the network goes through at book.  I tried "sudo service network-manager restart" without success.  When I look in my Network Settings box, the Xfinity nameserver is there.  So I think I just need to restart the network from the command line in a way that won't drop my remote connection.  I've read that some commands, like "ifdown && ifup" end up only going down, cutting the connection.  So I need something that will DEFINITELY restart up again.